# jquery ajax done and fail

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have this code:

```
$.when(saveData()).done(alert('ok')).fail(alert('not ok'));
```

The result is that both 'ok' and 'not ok' being alerted.

Jquery docs says that .done() is equivalent for success and .fail equivalent for failure
(source: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/)

My `saveData()` function:

```
function saveData()
        {
            var data_save = $('#eciform').serializeArray();
            return $.ajax
                ({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"inputajax.cfm?mode=3",
                    data:data_save                  
                });
        }
```

How can it return ok and not ok at the same time? It should either be success or failure. Is it maybe because it only work with GET and not POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.done() and .fail() needs to be inside function()

```
function doneCallback(){
    alert("this was ok");
}

function failCallback(){
    alert("this was not ok");
}

$.when(saveData()).done(doneCallback).fail(failCallback);
```

or simply

```
$.when(saveData()).done(function(){alert("ok");}).fail(function(){alert("not ok");});
```

Comment: What returns when() function?

Comment: as you can see, when is just calling saveData, which returns a jqXHR. When itself doesn't return anything

Comment: I uncluded saveData() function, if that helps you.

Comment: try $.when(saveData().done(alert('ok')).fail(alert('not ok'))); you have been using .when(...).done(...) and i think it needs to be .when(saveData().done())

Comment: $.when(saveData()).done(function(data){alert("ok")}).fail(function(data){alert('not ok')}); this one should work.

Comment: Thanks! this works. If you edit your answer with this, I'll upvote

Comment: The first code block is incorrect. You are executing both your "callbacks" when the `$.when().done().fail()` line is evaluated, their return values (undefined) are received by the promise and nothing will be invoked when the request actually finishes.